# Elasticsearch indices not respecting template nor mapping

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following fields in my custom template:

```
"srcBytes": {"type": "integer"},
"dstBytes": {"type": "integer"},
```

What is more, when retrieving the mapping for the specific index, this seems to be applied:

```
GET my_index-raw-data-2019.02.11/_mapping



      },
      "srcBytes": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
        "dstBytes": {
        "type": "integer"
```

Then why `kibana` keeps showing these fields as `t`?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to refresh the index pattern in kibana?

Comment: yep that was the issue; post it as an answer so that i can accept it;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably simply need to [refresh your index pattern](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/index-patterns.html#reload-fields) in Kibana so it picks up the latest mappings from your underlying index.